# Laravel Varbox 2.x - duplicate model with relationships included

Tags: laravel, eloquent, duplicates, clone

I’m using the `HasDuplicates` trait on my `Post` custom entity.
The `Post` has 2 relations:

- has many `comments`
- has one `author`

How can I configure the duplicate functionality in order to duplicate a post record along with its relationships: `comments` and `author`?

I see in your documentation that I have the option of excluding relations, but not to include them.

Comment: `HasDuplicates` isn't a trait in core, you should link to what package you're using.

Comment: @PatricNox he mentions in the title of the question that he's using Laravel Varbox 2.x

Answer (score 0):

The `Varbox\Traits\HasDuplicates` automatically duplicates all your eloquent model relationships by default, so that's why there's no option to include any relationships to be duplicated, because they all are duplicated by default.

Also, in the event where you don't want certain relations duplicated (such as `belongs to` relations), you have the option to exclude them (as you already stated): https://varbox.io/docs/2.x/duplicate-records#exclude-relations

So to answer your questions, you don't need to do anything to include your `comments` and `author` relations into the duplication functionality, as they will be included by default.

---

Suggestion: Depending on your database structure and logic architecture, I think you should consider converting the `author` relation into a `belongs to`, instead of `has one`, but that's up to you.